# Multiple use of same closure argument won't compile

Tags: swift

Why is it not compiling the following:

```
extension Array {

    func firstWhere(fn: (T) -> Bool) -> T? {
        for x in self {
            if fn(x) {
                return x
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

var view = UIView()
// Do setup here of view if you want (but shouldn't be necessary)

let x = view.subviews.firstWhere { $0.tag? == 1 && $0.userInteractionEnabled } as? UIView
```

Compiler is saying: Could not find member 'userInteractionEnabled'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the type of `view.subviews` is `[AnyObject]`, so you have to cast it to `[UIView]` first to have `userInteractionEnabled`.
So:

```
(view.subviews as! [UIView]).firstWhere( ... )
```

And I'm not sure which version of Xcode you are using, but this (I mean that the question mark at the end of `tag` is not needed):

```
let x = (view.subviews as! [UIView]).firstWhere { $0.tag == 1 && $0.userInteractionEnabled }
```

compiles fine in Xcode 6.3 .

Comment: Makes sense but how come a simple `let x = view.subviews.firstWhere { $0.userInteractionEnabled }` compiles without having to cast to `[UIView]`?

Comment: I don't think so. You have to cast to UIView to have `.userInteractionEnabled` cause firstWhere of [AnyObject] is an AnyObject

Comment: I'm not sure, it produces an error in my project. Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Xcode 6.3 - sorry I was missing a cast after `firstWhere`. This code compiles: `let x = view.subviews.firstWhere { $0.userInteractionEnabled } as? UIView` -- BUT this does not: `let x = view.subviews.firstWhere { $0.tag == 1 && $0.userInteractionEnabled } as? UIView`. Instead I have to do `let x = (view.subviews as! [UIView]).firstWhere { $0.tag == 1 && $0.userInteractionEnabled }`. I can live with it but just thought it was worth knowing/investigating.

Comment: @softbear interesting, the first way that you described in the comment above is does not compile in my project.

Comment: @DánielNagy, very interesting. I'm on version 6.3 (6D570) btw. You did remember to put a `as? UIView` in the end? It's almost as if the compiler (in my case) is able to infer the type of the closure argument for the first use, but not for subsequent usages (within the same closure).

Comment: @softbear I did, I copied it from your comment, so I'm not sure what could be here.

Comment: @DánielNagy, now I got it to error too. But I can make it disappear too, just by putting a newline after the statement. And I can make the error appear again by removing newlines before, or after the statement. Clearly a bug. I think I will stick with the more explicit code as you suggested going forward.

Comment: @softbear are you using this code in playground? If so, that could be the problem that it does not show this error correctly unlike in a project file.

Comment: I have it working in a project too.

http://oi60.tinypic.com/2egdurp.jpg

(apologies I inadvertently is breaking stackoverflow policies, it even suggests me moving it to chat but I don't have enough reputation yet)

Comment: @softbear In this case it could be a bug as you said.